# Convert AS3 to FLA for generating SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, adobe, flex4.6

I Need to manipulate the compiled SWF and recompile it back to SWF and deploy. I have tried 3 options but no luck on all the options :

1) Converting swf to fla to AS3, I was able to edit the AS3 file, then I am not able to move forward to create the new FLA & new SWF file.

2) Converting swf to flex project and importing to flex builder, then while publishing it says that I did not main MXML file to get new SWF.

3) Currently I had tried converting AS3 to FLA, but no luck.

If you have any known options to convert AS3 to FLA sucessfully please let me know,  I will be monitoring the thread!..

UPDATE 1 ) : I had tried converting SWF to FLA from SWF decomplier , it was successful , but the problem was how do i edit it and convert it back new SWF again.  My Aim , was to add few strings or names, After decompiling it , i got both FLA , bunch of AS3 files , after editing my AS3 files and i am not able to convert All bunch of AS3 files together to make a new SWF or new FLA ... Please respond Thanks for other replies!...

> Update 2: Thanks for your previous replies guys , i think i cannot
>   find the correct library that was from the previous import errors , do
>   u know how , were can i find it. IS Embedding asset types help me to
>   solve this kind of errors. please look at this thread let me know
>   ["Error #1014: Class mx.core::BitmapAsset could not be found" while trying to use Runtime Shared Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989444/error-1014-class-mx-corebitmapasset-could-not-be-found-while-trying-to-use)
>   ,  If any body knows this please reply , It will be a great help..

Comment: FLA - Adobe Flash source file. SWF - compiled Flash application. AS3 aka ActionScript3 is a name of programming language/script. What you are asking is, like, "how to convert English into library building" and makes no much sense therefor.

Comment: You could use SWF Decompiler to create a FLA from an SWF, but most of the time the FLA won't be as easy to work with as the original FLA. http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler

Comment: Organis : your saying that it was not possible to convert AS3 to FLA or SWF ?...

Comment: Kokodoko : thanks for your reply ,  please check the update section that i had added , and let me know your thoughts on it!..Please respond!..

Comment: Kokodoko , Organis , please provide use any thoughts , if u know , i had added my updateds..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the FLA in an appropriate editor (usually [Flash Professional](http://www.adobe.com/products/animate.html), or other IDEs such as [Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html), [Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex.html), etc...)
2. Compile (<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> for Flash Professional)

To clarify:

- `.swf` is a compiled Flash program (with embedded code, text, and assets).
- `.fla` is a project file that holds the references to everything you want to compile.
- `.as` file is the code used in the program.
- `.mxml` file is an XML document that contains markup for layout and chunks of code.  Usually present with a Flex based project.

A word of warning: a decompiler will not always be successful in reconstructing the project.  It is entirely possible that the files you get out of it cannot be recompiled apart from some esoteric settings that the original developer had present.

Comment: thanks for your reply , i tried compiling from cs flash professional 5.5 but it says , SpiriteAssests are not defined , biteassets are not defined , flexdiplay are not defined , this were i am completely stuck , can u please let me know how should i move forward!..

Comment: Usually this indicates there are missing imports at the top of your document.  For instance, if you use a Sprite in a class without first calling `import flash.display.Sprite;`, however, it could also be there were library items by those same names in the project that are being called in the code, and are not present.  Unfortunately, decompiling is not a sure thing.  You'll have to work through each problem independently.

Comment: yes ,thanks for your previous reply, i cannot find the correct library that was from the errors that i have previously , do u know how to find .do u think Embedding asset types help me to solve this kind of errors. please look at my Updated comments above and let me know  if u know that it will be a great help.. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ff2.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fa3 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989444/error-1014-class-mx-corebitmapasset-could-not-be-found-while-trying-to-use